# How to work on this particular situation in django admin?

Tags: python, django

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar_protected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=50
```

Here I am customizing django admin. Now I have two field in the model. By Default I want that 'bar' remains disabled. (Not Hide). And bar_protected unchecked. When some one checked bar_protected , bar enabled.

```
    Django have disabled facilities But when I do, It hides the bar Field.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reword your question to make it more legible.

Answer (score 3):

You should either use `editable = False` in the model for that field or put it in `readonly_fields` while registering the model in the admin.py file. This should work.